# Creating Feature vector in .mat file for training dataset

Tags: matlab, image-processing, feature-extraction

I wanted to create a feature vector for training dataset and wanted to store all feature as rows in the.mat file. The .mat file must be in the form [Feature Vector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8L9z.jpg). I am able to extract Feature of 1 image and store it in excel file or .mat file but not able to extract all image feature and store it in .mat file. Can anyone knows this?

Its something like appending the same variables in the same .mat file. I have tried

```
save('feat.mat','feature','-append');
```

Where 'feature' is an array

```
feature = [mydata, stats{k}];
```

I have a folder which contains images who's feature I wanted to extract and store as training dataset. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: When you say you are "Not able to extract all image feature" what is the issue, specifically? Are you receiving an error, or is the data you expect not being saved? According to the documentation, the append parameter for `save` will overwrite existing variables of the same name in the .mat file. Could you be overwriting the variable each time?

Answer (score 0):

the code was rectified.

```
stats = graycoprops(GLCM_values{'contrast','homogeneity','Correlation','Energy'});
```

stats was a structure so converted into the array using

```
features=struct2array(stats);
```

and was able to save the features